# Why my script is started to run but not showing results table in non gui mode in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

I started jmeter servers in both slave machines and in master machine run the script.
server connected and script started to run but not showing any result table.long time waited but still not showing anything. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that i have done everything correct but,i was using

> ./jmeter-server -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[server IP]

command to run the server but for starting client i was not using -Djava.rmi.server.hostname command.

when i used it like

> [ec2-user@ip-serverip bin]$ ./jmeter.sh -n -t remotetest.jmx -l log1.csv -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=[client_Server_ip] -R[server1_IP:port],[server2_IP:port]

it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It might mean that your RMI configuration is not correct and slaves cannot send results back to master.

1. Check [jmeter-server.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) on slave machines for any suspicious entries.
2. Check that the port you defined as `client.rmi.localport` and 3 ports starting from the value you've specified are open in OS [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing)) and [AWS Security groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-security-groups.html)

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Apache JMeter Distributed Testing Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.html)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)